# border appearing around mediaelement.js (2.16.4) focused element

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm seeing a border appear around MediaElement.js video and audio elements when the video/audio is played (and, in some cases, the border doesn't disappear when the focus is removed, but that's a lesser issue at present).  I'm seeing the issue in Safari, Chrome and Firefox--not so much in IE for whatever reason.  The issue appears in the code I've included below, but it does NOT appear on the MediaElement.js home page:

http://mediaelementjs.com

I assume this means it's a CSS thing, but I'm puzzled why it wouldn't be part of the default MEJS skin CSS.  Hopefully I'm just doing something stupid.  Help?

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">      
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <link  href="mediaelement-2.16.4/mediaelementplayer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="mediaelement-2.16.4/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('video,audio').mediaelementplayer();
        });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <video src="sample.mp4" poster="mountain.jpg" width="640" height="264"></video>
    <hr>
    <audio src="sample.mp3" preload="auto">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I figured it out (sheepishly ducks head).

The MediaElement site is using a CSS reset which includes this line:

:focus { outline: 0; }

...which, obviously, removes focus.  Somewhat odd, now that I'm thinking about it, that this line isn't part of the MediaElement CSS. I can't imagine anybody ever wanting this behavior...